# HTTP Error when running code to fetch file from github

Tags: python, github

I am trying to fetch and create a dataset from a dataset on GitHub based on code from hands on ml. The problem is however, when I try and run this code I keep getting an HTTP Error 404 error message. Not sure what could be causing this.

Here is a detailed traceback of the error message I am receiving:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6ada1818e178> in <module>
----> 1 fetch_housing()

<ipython-input-15-981f9394002a> in fetch_housing(housing_url, housing_path)
      5     tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path,'housing.tgz')
      6     print(tgz_path)
----> 7     urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url,tgz_path)
      8     housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
      9     housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

This is the code I am using

```
download_root = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/hanson-ml/master/'
housing_path = os.path.join('datasets','housing')
housing_url = download_root+'datasets/housing/housing.tgz'

def fetch_housing(housing_url = housing_url,housing_path=housing_path):
        if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
            os.makedirs(housing_path)
        tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path,'housing.tgz')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url,tgz_path)
        housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
        housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
        housing_tgz.close()
```

Comment: `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` ?

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek housing_url prints out a valid url

Comment: if you go in a browser you will see that results in a plain 404. The url is valid, but the site is not responding at this address. Maybe the dataset was moved or deleted ? Anyway we can't find the dataset for you...